# SQLiteException: no such column: image_data (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, image_data, name, description, residence, status FROM friends

Tags: android-sqlite

I have a databse app. Initially I wanted to put details of individuals. Later I wanted to display their image. Here is my SQLiteOpenHeloer class---

```
public class FriendsDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public FriendsDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, FriendContract.FriendEntry.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        updateData(db,0,FriendContract.FriendEntry.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        updateData(db,oldVersion,newVersion);
    }

    private void updateData(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion)
    {
        if(oldVersion<1)
        {
            String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    + FriendContract.FriendEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + FriendContract.FriendEntry.NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + FriendContract.FriendEntry.DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
                    + FriendContract.FriendEntry.RESIDENCE + " TEXT,"
                    + FriendContract.FriendEntry.STATUS + " TEXT );";    
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
        }    
        if(oldVersion<2)
        {
            String SQL_CREATE_TABLE="ALTER TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+ "ADD COLUMN "+ KEY_IMAGE +"BLOB";
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
        }    
    }
}
```

Here is FriendContract class---

```
public  class FriendContract {

    private FriendContract()
    {    
    }

    public static final class FriendEntry implements BaseColumns {

        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;    
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends";   
        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;    
        public static final String NAME = "name";    
        public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";    
        public static final String RESIDENCE = "residence";    
        public static final String STATUS = "status";    
        public static final String KEY_IMAGE="image_data";    
    }
}
```

It shows an error-----

SQLiteException: no such column: image_data (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, image_data, name, description, residence, status FROM friends

It points the error to the following line in main activity---

`Cursor newCursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[]{_ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,RESIDENCE,STATUS,KEY_IMAGE},null,null,null,n`ull,null);

What is the error? Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this :-

```
String SQL_CREATE_TABLE="ALTER TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+ "ADD COLUMN "+ KEY_IMAGE +"BLOB";
```

This resolves to `ALTER TABLE friendsADD COLUMN image_dataBLOB`

You need a space between the table name and ADD and between column name and the column type i.e. it should be :-

```
String SQL_CREATE_TABLE="ALTER TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+ " ADD COLUMN "+ KEY_IMAGE +" BLOB"; //<<<< space added before BLOB
```